# Get highest id using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of note `div`s in the following format:

```
<div class="note-row" id="1">
<div class="note-row" id="2">
<div class="note-row" id="4">
<div class="note-row" id="5">
<div class="note-row" id="6">
```

How would I get the largest `id` using javascript? So far I have:

```
$('.note-row').each(function() {
    ??
});
```

Comment: According to the HTML Spec, IDs cannot start with a number.

Comment: Except in HTML5 and eventually higher.

Comment: If the elements are arranged in order by ID and only these elements has class `note-row` then you can do it using `.last`. -> `$('.note-row').last()[0].id`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Quick and dirty way:

```
var max = 0;
$('.note-row').each(function() {
    max = Math.max(this.id, max);
});
console.log(max);
```

This is a little shorter and more sophisticated (for using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), and also allowing negative ids down to `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`, as suggested by Blazemonger):

```
var max = $('.note-row').get().reduce(function(a, b){
    return Math.max(a, b.id)
}, Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
```

Comment: +1, much more efficient than the other answer which uses `map` and `sort`.

Comment: `max = Math.max(this.id,max)` beats an if-then statement any day.

Comment: @Blazemonger Thanks. I was wondering if I needed to add parseInt too, and Math.max should take care of that too. Updated.

Comment: Gonna push for an initial value of `max = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` here as well. :-)

Comment: @Blazemonger Nice, used that in an alternate solution based on [].reduce.

Comment: Your second version seems more complicated and inefficient than your first version.

Comment: @Vega That's sort of what I meant with "sophisticated". But why inneficient? Because of the `.toArray call`? It can be avoided with `Array.prototype.reduce.call($('.note-row'), ...`, but that would make it look even more complicated.

Comment: Replaced `toArray` with `get` because, well, it's shorter. ;-)

Comment: Caveat: [`reduce` may require a polyfill in older browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Compatibility).

Comment: @Blazemonger I just ran some performance tests you might be interested in: http://jsperf.com/stack-overflow-question-15371102.

Answer (score 8):

You could do something like this:

```
var ids = $('.note-row').map(function() {
    return parseInt(this.id, 10);
}).get();

var max = Math.max.apply(Math, ids);
```

Comment: Except this doesn't actually get the highest for me. The highest in the set I have is 20, whereas this gives me 9.

Comment: Other than being inefficient, this will not work as `.sort` in JS doesn't work with numbers as you'd expect.

Comment: @Dogbert: If you're going for efficiency, don't use jQuery in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Funny but this also works:

```
var max = $('.note-row').sort(function(a, b) { return +a.id < +b.id })[0].id;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N5zWe/

Comment: Ideally sort comparator functions are supposed to return -1 ot 0 or 1.

Comment: @Vega I know, but in this case it's not necessary since we are looking for the max value. Anyway I provided this solution just for the sake of curiosity. Of course it sucks.

Answer (score 2):

In the interest of completeness, an optimized [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) solution:

```
var n = document.getElementsByClassName('note-row'),
    m = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
    i = 0,
    j = n.length;
for (;i<j;i++) {
    m = Math.max(n[i].id,m);
}
console.log(m);
```

Comment: [This is the fastest technique](http://jsperf.com/stack-overflow-question-15371102/2), if not necessarily the shortest code.

Answer (score 0):

The same way you'd find any max, loop:

```
var max = -999; // some really low sentinel

$('.note-row').each(function() {
    var idAsNumber = parseInt(this.id, 10);
    if (idAsNumber  > max) {
        max = idAsNumber;
    }
});
```

Comment: `max = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` is the initial value you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var maxID = -1;
  $('.note-row').each(function() {
       var myid = parseInt($(this).attr('id'),10);
       if( maxID < myid ) maxID = myid;
  });
  // the value of maxID will be the max from id-s
```